# Cherry-pick only certain commits from a branch

Tags: git, github

I am working on a repo that looks like this:

```
A-B <--(master)
   \
    C-D-E-F <--(features)
```

However, the owner would like me to split my commits into separate branches, like this:

```
A-B
   \
    +-C   <--(Feature-A)
    +-D-F <--(Feature-B)
    +-E   <--(Feature-C)
```

I feel like this should be a text-book cherry-pick, but I can't figure it out.  This is further complicated by the fact I've already pushed the C-D-E-F (features) branch up to my clone of the repo.

I tried doing

```
git rebase --onto B E
```

but it is not giving me the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to easily do this that I know of, but fairly simple (C, D and E are revision of C, D and E in your illiustration):

```
git branch Feature-A C
git checkout -b Feature-B master
git cherry-pick D
git cherry-pick features
git checkout -b Feature-C master
git cherry-pick E
git branch -D features
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch FeatureA B
git checkout FeatureA
git cherry-pick C
```

Comment: What is FA in the first line?

Comment: @jsexauer branch name